# why query update does not workin at all

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, updates

So I've been trying to change my code to any other ways that can fit but nothing happened... I want to change `status_data_user` to be nonactive from active but it cannot works.. on my other delete codes is working without any troubles.

I've been changing it to

```
$hapus = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tb_user SET status_data_user='$status_data_user',created_at='$created_at', updated_at='$updated_at' WHERE id_user='$id_user'");
```

```
$x="UPDATE tb_user SET status_data_user='$status_data_user',created_at='$created_at', updated_at='$updated_at' WHERE id_user='$id_user'";
$hapus = mysqli_query($conn, $x);
```

Comment: You should add error checking. You should also learn how to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: what does `$id_user` have in it ,check onces.

Comment: Can you please check what is the data type of **status_data_user** field in database? Are you passing proper value in status_data_user field in update query?

Comment: @RajdipChauhan its varchar

Comment: @Swati did u mean this?? $id_log           = "";
$id_user          = $row_user['id_user'];
$aksi             = "edit user";
$ip_address       = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$status_data_user = "nonaktif";
$status_data_log  = "aktif";
$created_at       = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$updated_at       = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Comment: if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id_user = $_GET['id'];
}else{
  die("error no id selected");
}
    $data="SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE id_user=$id_user";
    $q               = mysqli_query($conn, $data);
    $hasil           = mysqli_fetch_array($q);
    $id_user         = $hasil['id_user'];
    $nama            = $hasil['nama'];
    $username        = $hasil['username'];
    $password        = $hasil['password'];
    $lvl_user        = $hasil['lvl_user'];
    $status_data_user="nonaktif";

Comment: [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1T8ipLKrNcgqJWuCNxTOAQrxUfdEv7ygrmVGV1mljbqk/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: Follow this steps. 1) Just change the table name (Something like tb_user1) and run the query, 2) Now u will get the error with your sql query and variable values. 3) Now copy this query and rename table name to original name and run this in phpmyadmin panel, here you will get clear idea

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The thing is that you are using the php variables in the string itself, as it will be interprated by PHP as char values but not Variables. So try to use like

`"UPDATE tb_user SET status_data_user='".$status_data_user."',created_at='".$created_at."', updated_at='".$updated_at."' WHERE id_user='".$id_user."'";`

The method you are using by putting variables in string is often used in PHP Laravel Framework, because it has Blade extensions that can interpret variables within the string.

Hope it helps

Comment: Psst. plz check that you are sending correct date format to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

```
$x="UPDATE tb_user SET status_data_user='".$status_data_user."',created_at='".$created_at."', updated_at='".$updated_at."' WHERE id_user='".$id_user."'";
$hapus = mysqli_query($conn, $x);
```

Answer (score -1):

Issue is that, you are passing php variable value in single comma, You can pass it like below

```
$x="UPDATE tb_user SET status_data_user='".$status_data_user."',created_at='".$created_at."', updated_at='".$updated_at."' WHERE id_user='".$id_user."'";
$hapus = mysqli_query($conn, $x);
```

Comment: There is no issue in update query I mention above, may be you have any other issue related data passing in it. may be other's field value.